# Custom OpenLiberty HttpRequestFilter to use API-Keys

Tags: java, open-liberty

I'm using OpenLiberty 22 and my Java 17 EE application is secured with `mpJwt-1.2` feature. My mpJwt configuration in `server.xml` looks like following:

```
<mpJwt audiences="ALL_AUDIENCES"
       authFilterRef="api-key-filter"
       groupNameAttribute="groupIds"
       id="myJwt"
       issuer="***"
       jwksUri="***"
       userNameAttribute="sub" >
</mpJwt>

<authFilter id="api-key-filter">
    <requestHeader matchType="notContain" name="X-API-Key"/>
</authFilter>
```

With the `authFilter` I tell the server to not validate incoming requests where header 'X-API-Key' Authentication header is set. All other calls should be validated with mpJwt as usual. Now I would like to check whether value of `X-API-Key` is valid or not and in case of invalid, return 401. My problem is, that with my `web.xml` config entries all calls with api key header are rejected with 401 directly due to this security constraint.

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Web Application</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>AllAuthenticated</role-name>         
    </auth-constraint>      
</security-constraint>
```

This security constraint is needed to enable mpJwt validation in OpenLiberty.

## My Question

Is it possible to write a custom OpenLiberty Feature to check `HttpRequestHeader` in combination with an `authFilter` as it is in mpJwt (`authFilterRef`)? Or is it possible to configure server to get this behaviour?

The only way I found is to unsecure these routes explicitly in `server.xml` but this is very unflexible, because I always have to added this routes explicitly and mpJwt validation is disabled for each call to this routes.

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Public</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/customApiKeyRoute1/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/customApiKeyRoute2/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
</security-constraint>
```